# Why the '\n' symbol is in numpy empty array?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

During debug I see this:
[image]

It is just creation of empty array... Why '\n'? How to make array without it?

Comment: Who said zeros is empty?

Comment: That's just your IDE being weird. The array doesn't have a `\n` in it (or commas or brackets, for that matter).

Comment: Who said the `\n` is actually part of the array for that matter?

Comment: I don't know what IDE this is but it looks like it is just giving you `str(np.zeros(1000))` so you can see what it looks like (and confuse you ;) )

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### Program to create a numpy array of zeros

```
# Python 3.x
import numpy as np
y1 = np.zeros(100)
print(y1)
print("Shape of y1")
print(y1.shape)
```

I have directed the output of this into a 'tester.txt' file

```
python3 numpynewline.py >> tester.txt
```

The output although has a newline for displays, the shape of the array is not effected by it

[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]

**Shape of y1**
(100,)

**Just 100 elements**

The output just looks to be having a newline for display, there is no actual **'\n'** in the array, you must be reading the **y1** through a terminal or something, otherwise the normal python is not having any such characteristic of creating a numpy array with **'\n'** character

**Implemented on Ubuntu 17.04, and Python 3.6**